# How to add new field in product attribute options in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute, catalog, custom-field, attribute-options

I want to add custom field for attribute options in Magento 2

how can I do?

Comment: Hi @vinod-kumar, did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: Not found. after that client's requirement has changed. so didn't check

Answer (score -2):

Please follow this tutorial to create new product attribute.
https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/

Comment: I am talking about add custom field into options of the product attribute. For example: I have color attribute and the options are Red, Green Black, Blue etc....Now I want to add new custom field description with each option.